# Aggregate boolean values to true if any of the source columns is true

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, boolean-logic

Let say I have the following table:

```
id   column_a  column_b   column_c
1     t          f           t
2     t          f           f
3     f          t           f
```

From the above table, I want to:

```
select rows from id = 1,2;
```

The result should be:

```
column_a   column_b   column_c
 t          f            t
```

If any of the rows among the defined id has a true for a particular column we assume the result to be true.

Comment: Every column and every row has at least one true, so I don't see why you would not be expecting back the entire table.  Can you clarify your logic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the aggregate function [`bool_or()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html).

```
SELECT bool_or(column_a) AS column_a
     , bool_or(column_b) AS column_b
     , bool_or(column_c) AS column_c
FROM   tbl
WHERE  id IN (1,2);
```

The manual:

> true if at least one input value is true, otherwise false

Comment: you are great! Didn't knew about the function bool_or

Comment: Can these column_a, column_b, column_c values be stored into an array such as : [t,f,t]

Comment: @SyedAsadAbbasZaidi: Sure. Please ask your question as question. Comments are not the place.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40415894/create-array-for-values-from-list-of-columns-extracted-in-postgres

Answer (score 0):

`bool_or(...)` is definitely your best friend here.

Just one thing to remember which manual doesn't mention: If all values supplied to `bool_or` are `null`, the result will be `null` too.