# Create array for values from list of columns extracted in Postgres

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have following set of table:

```
id   column_a  column_b   column_c
1     t          f           t
2     t          f           f
3     f          t           f
```

Which when queried by:

```
SELECT bool_or(column_a) AS column_a
     , bool_or(column_b) AS column_b
     , bool_or(column_c) AS column_c
FROM   tbl
WHERE  id IN (1,2);
```

gives result as:

```
column_a   column_b   column_c
 t          f            t
```

I wanted to get the array from the result as: `[t,f,t]` in Postgres.

Please have reference to the earlier stack question over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40415401/aggregate-boolean-values-to-true-if-any-of-the-source-columns-is-true/40415454).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an [ARRAY constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS):

```sql
SELECT ARRAY [bool_or(column_a)
            , bool_or(column_b)
            , bool_or(column_c)] AS arr_abc
FROM   tbl
WHERE  id IN (1,2);
```